# Concatenating data while copying the data

Tags: vba, excel

I am working with a large dataset. I am attempting to trim the data.

Thanks to looking on stackoverflow I was able to modify some code to fit my needs almost.

```
Sub CopyData()
Dim sourceColumn As Range, targetColumn As Range

Set sourceColumn = Workbooks("Parcels Data.xlsm").Worksheets("Parcels").Columns("A")
Set targetColumn = Workbooks("Parcel Data for NSDB.xlsm").Worksheets("Imported").Columns("A")

sourceColumn.Copy Destination:=targetColumn
Set sourceColumn = Workbooks("Parcels Data.xlsm").Worksheets("Parcels").Columns("B")
Set targetColumn = Workbooks("Parcel Data for NSDB.xlsm").Worksheets("Imported").Columns("B")

sourceColumn.Copy Destination:=targetColumn

End Sub
```

This imports what I need.

I need to concatenate columns B and C together with a space in between the values. This new file will be used for being imported into other databases so I need it in a specific format.

I have been trying to figure out how to use '&' while using Range.Copy. I can not just use '&' because it is not a string since I am dealing with ranges. Is it possible to concatenate at the same point in time as copying the data?

Comment: What's the question, how to concatenate two values together? `=A1&" "&B1` in a cell will take what's in `A1` and `B1`, and separate with a space.

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more clear in my question. I have been trying to figure out how to use '&' while using Range.Copy. I can not just use '&' because it is not a string since I am dealing with ranges. Is it possible to concatenate at the same point in time as copying the data?

Comment: @Grant Nope, you'll have to loop over the values in the range and concat one by one- or read them into an array etc as Pierre suggests.  Realistically though depending in the size of your data this should not take a long time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Sub CopyData()
Dim source, dest, i&
With Workbooks("Parcels Data.xlsm").Worksheets("Parcels")
    source = Range(.Range("A1"), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 2)).Value
End With
ReDim dest(1 To UBound(source), 1 To 1)
For i = 1 To UBound(dest)
    dest(i,1) = source(i, 1) & " " & source(i, 2)
Next
With Workbooks("Parcel Data for NSDB.xlsm").Worksheets("Imported")
    Range(.Range("A1"), .Cells(UBound(dest), 1)) = dest
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, once I figured out how the code worked I was able to modify to fill out all of the columns I needed. This helped so much!

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a loop- you cant do it for the entire range at once.  This should get you started:

```
Sub Concat()

Dim lRow As Long

lRow = Range("B" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To lRow
    Range("C" & i) = Range("A"& i) & " " & Range("B" & i)
Next i

End Sub
```